# RSS Not Validating with spaces in CDATA

Tags: xml, rss

I have a third party app creating RSS XML. There are spaces within the CDATA text, that makes validation fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Title</title>
<link>http://www.example.com/</link>
<description>Description</description>
<image>
    <title>Title</title>
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/some image/image.jpg]]></url>
    <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
</image>
<item>
    <title>Item title</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
    <description>Description</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I don't have control over the CDATA enclosed text. But I can confirm the URL in question takes me to the image when visited directly from a browser. The error I get is `Invalid character in a URI`, and when I manually edit the file on the server to remove the space the RSS validates.

Encoding the space `%20` seems to work. But I'm not sure how to do this ongoing. Could I change the XML output to be PHP perhaps and have the url encoded by the server when it's loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to PHP and using `rawurlencode` did the job, not `urlencode` which replaced spaces with a `+`

```
<? php echo '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Title</title>
<link>http://www.example.com/</link>
<description>Description</description>
<image>
    <title>Title</title>
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/';?><?php echo rawurlencode('some image/image.jpg');?><?php echo ']]></url>
    <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
</image>
<item>
    <title>Item title</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com/</link>
    <description>Description</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>'?>
```

Don't forget to change the file type to php, and echo out all/any text you need rendered by the server.